# How to stop re-write rules for existing files located in virtual language folders (.htaccess)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

In my .htaccess all requested urls that can't be found are being rewritten to main.php using the code below:

```
RewriteCond $1 ^ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ main.php?document=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This means if someone is typing `www.my-site.com/contact_us.php` that page will show since that file exists and the rewrite rule above will not be applied.

The problem is when using multi-languages, since I use a virtual folder for each language. For example Italian will be:

`www.my-site.com/it/contact_us.php`

How can I stop the re-write rule above for all existing files located in these virtual folders?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond $1 ^

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ main.php?lang=$1&document=$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ main.php?document=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your rule like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$2 !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$2 !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ main.php?lang=$1&document=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ main.php?document=$1 [L,QSA]
```